# OpenCV document scan algorithm

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing  the document Scanner app like Office lens. Live edge detection but it not Detecting accurately .I developing app using opencv with ndk in android studio

My algorithm

```
  extern "C"
 JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL
   Java_com_example_lenovo_cricledection_MainActivitysca_doWithMat(JNIEnv 
  *env, 
  jobject instance,
                                                  jlong matAddrGr, jlong 
 matAddrRgba) {

 Mat &image = *(Mat *) matAddrRgba;
  Rect bounding_rect;

 Mat thr(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC1);
 cvtColor(image, thr, CV_BGR2GRAY); //Convert to gray
threshold(thr, thr, 150, 255, THRESH_BINARY + THRESH_OTSU); //Threshold 
  the gray

vector<vector<Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
findContours(thr, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,
         CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE); // Find the contours in the image
 sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(),
 compareContourAreas);            //Store the index of largest contour
 bounding_rect = boundingRect((const _InputArray &) contours[0]);

 rectangle(image, bounding_rect, Scalar(250, 250, 250) , 3);
  jclass rectClass = env->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Rect");
  jmethodID rectCtorID = env->GetMethodID(rectClass, "<init>", "(IIII)V");
  return env->NewObject(rectClass, rectCtorID, bounding_rect.x, 
  bounding_rect.y, 
  bounding_rect.width, bounding_rect.height);

}
```

My Output

[image: Image Output]

My Question:

1.How to FindContour of document

2.How to crop Detect Document in android